# PHP Navigation Bar and Login Page

Tags: php

I created a login page but by only using PHP (no MySQL), but when the you logged in, the "menu.php" (this is the navigation bar) never refresh. I tried a method when you logged in into my server, it will automatically reload, but when the page reload you are getting to be redirected in my login page. Is there a way to fix this issue? [sorry if my English is bad =(]

This is my "login.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
$user["stackoverflow"] = "isawesome";

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            exit('<br /><br /><html><body><div id="center"><h2> Login Status: <br/></h2><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">Please fill in all fields!</span></div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"></body>');
        }
        elseif ($user[$_POST['username']] != $_POST['password'])
        {
            exit('<br /><br /><div id="center"><h2> Login Status: <br/></h2><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">Your username/password is wrong!</span></div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"></body>');
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isset($_SESSION['ingelogd']))
            echo '<div id="center"><h2> Login Status: <br/></h2><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold">You are now logged in!</span></div>';
    }
    else
    {
        exit('<br /><br />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/body.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/button.css">
<div id="center">
        <form method="POST" action=""><p>
        Username:<br />
        <input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
        Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> <input type="reset" value="Empty fields" />
        </form></div>');
    }
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/body.css">
```

This is my "menu.php" (the navigation bar)

```
<?php
session_start();
//if user is logged in, \"user\" toolbox will show
if (isset($_SESSION['ingelogd']) && $_SESSION['ingelogd'] == true) {
    echo "<ul id=\"menu\">
  <li class=\"li\"><a class=\"active\" href=\"#home\">Home</a></li>
  <li class=\"li\"><a id=\"a\" href=\"html/info/news.html\">News</a></li>
  <li class=\"li\"><a id=\"a\" href=\"html/info/contact.html\">Contact</a></li>
  <li class=\"li\"><a id=\"a\" href=\"html/info/about.html\">About</a></li>
  <li class=\"li\"><a id=\"a\" href=\"html/auth/logout.php\" style=\"float:right\">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
<br/>";
}
//if not logged in, this will show
 else {
    echo "<ul id=\"menu\">
  <li class=\"li\"><a class=\"active\" href=\"#home\">Home</a></li>
  <li class=\"li\"><a id=\"a\" href=\"html/info/news.html\">News</a></li>
  <li class=\"li\"><a id=\"a\" href=\"html/info/contact.html\">Contact</a></li>
  <li class=\"li\"><a id=\"a\" href=\"html/info/about.html\">About</a></li>
  <li class=\"li\"><a id=\"a\" href=\"html/auth/login.php\" style=\"float:right\">Log in</a></li>
</ul>
<br/>";
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/menu.css">
```

If you need to see other files, i'm glad to send it just to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for loggedin session like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
```

but you are setting the session like this

```
$_SESSION['ingelogd'] = true;
```

so change

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
```

to

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['ingelogd']))
```

Comment: change that in Login.php. make sure all the session keys are the same

Comment: I've added that, so what should really do? (sorry for asking the dumb questions =( )